# How to subscribe for multiple items with paypal?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have series of subscription plans, among which user can select anyone and make payments via paypal but apart from that, there is one extra facility one may want to avail with any of the package .i.e. that is home delivery.

I have taken help from this site : [LINK](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/subscriptions/html.html#1033038)

But there is no option for adding 2nd item that can be selected as checkbox with any of the plan. I tried this code

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
```

But using this code, I now can't even see the original "plan" name which was displayed before on paypal site.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 2nd drop-down option using the on1 variable.

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Product Test">Product Test</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly : $1.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="Yearly">Yearly : $2.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="5 - Year">5 - Year : $3.00 USD - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Colors">Colors</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
    <option value="Red">Red </option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue </option>
    <option value="Black">Black </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```